# Swift Unable to bridge NSNumber to Int

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UITableView` inside `UIViewController`

```
var userHistory: [[String: Any]] = [[String: Any]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    Alamofire.request("http://...").responseJSON { (response) in
        if let responseValue = response.result.value as! [String: Any]? {
            if let responseFoods = responseValue["orders"] as! [[String: Any]]? {
                self.userHistory = responseFoods
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "basCell", for: indexPath) as! BasCollectionViewCell

    let history = userHistory[indexPath.row]
    cell.numberLbl?.text = String(history["id"] as! Int)
    cell.statusLbl?.text = (history["status"] as? String) ?? ""
    let cost = String(history["price"] as! Int) 
    cell.sumLbl?.text = String(cost.dropLast(2)
    cell.dateLbl?.text = (history["date"] as? String) ?? ""

    return cell
}
```

The problem is that when I test on Simulator , my iPad mini , iPad Pro, iPhone 7 -  everything is fine and there are no mistakes

But when Im launch on iPhone 5 give me error :

> Fatal error: Unable to bridge NSNumber to Int: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-902.0.48/src/swift/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSNumber.swift, line 367

And

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unable to bridge NSNumber to Int

opposite `let cost = String(history["price"] as! Int)`

I can't understand what type of this problem

Comment: What is `userHistory`? Use custom struct or class rather than dictionary then you get rid of that issue magically.

Comment: @vadian , Im update code to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the value of the number in your question so I can't confirm this 100%.  However, since you said it works fine on newer devices but fails on the iPhone 5, I think you're dealing with a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue.

If you google this, you'll find the following:

> beginning with the iPhone 5S and the iPad Air in 2013, all of Apple’s
>   iPhones, iPads, and iPods since have included 64-bit chips.

According to the Swift Documentation: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

> Int In most cases, you don’t need to pick a specific size of integer
>   to use in your code. Swift provides an additional integer type, Int,
>   which has the same size as the current platform’s native word size:
>
> On a 32-bit platform, Int is the same size as Int32.
>
> On a 64-bit platform, Int is the same size as Int64.
>
> Unless you need to work with a specific size of integer, always use
>   Int for integer values in your code. This aids code consistency and
>   interoperability. Even on 32-bit platforms, Int can store any value
>   between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, and is large enough for many
>   integer ranges.

Is your value outside the 32-bit Int range?

Comment: Ok but how I can identify this?

Comment: Well, Swift Int64 variables work fine on 32-bit platforms so you could just convert to that instead.  However, you could always log out the values in your code prior to trying to casting to Int (to determine if it exceeds the 2.1B number).

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 has made the `NSNumber` bridging stricter. If the `NSNumber` can't be represented by an `Int`, the cast fails at runtime.
You could typecast it as `Double` instead, but since you mentioned that this fails on iPhone 5 only, we'll safely typecast it for both cases.

Replace:

```
let cost = String(history["price"] as! Int)
```

with:

```
var cost = ""
if let price = dict["price"] as? Int {
    cost = "\(price)"
}
else if let price = dict["price"] as? Double {
    cost = "\(price)"
}
```

Comment: Much easier to cast to Int64.

Comment: @gnasher729 But it's possible that this will fail if OP's number fits into an `Int`. i.e. Something like this will fail: `let dict: [String:Any] = ["price":1050]` `let cost = dict["price"] as! Int64`